# Python - AWS Cognito require verification email confirmation on user email change

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I've been looking through the [AWS Cognito](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.update_user_attributes) docs for Python. When a user wants to change their email on my app, a verification email should be sent to that new email address to ensure they own it and once that's clicked it should change the email attribute. I can change the user email easily with `update_user_attributes()`, but the issue is that I don't see a way to require the user to be verified via an email before that change is initiated. It's also harder to deal with, because Cognito is disentangled from the server. Any suggestions how to implement this feature with Cognito? More than likely I think I'll have to implement the verification email part myself and call Cognito server when the user is verified.

Comment: How is your User Pool configured? Do you allow users to sign in with email address? Then it's by default required to be verified. If not, then you need to code the whole thing yourself (to check if email is already verified before you allow users to change it). Also, email is changed immediately and only the attribute `email_verified` is set to `false`.

Comment: @AleksanderWons I know for certain it requires verification when you register, but I don't think that's true if you change the email address no? I think if you call that API via Boto3 it just does it and doesn't require verification.

Comment: Yes, it does require verification. `email_verified` is changed to `false` and you need to call `verify_user_attribute` (while user still has valid access token) to confirm it.